# Do I need "one" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never
>   heard of anyone falling inside (one) and dying frozen.

Do I need "one" in that sentence? Why or why not?

Comment: You don't need ***one*** for the same reason you don't need to go the whole hog and say *falling inside **a refrigerator*** (it's contextually obvious). But I have to say I don't think many people would accept your (adverbial?) *dying **froze*** (or ***frozen***) there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is "dying frozen" not correct in the same vein as "he died drunk"? Both are used as an adjective which describes the person's state at the time of death (edit: come to think of it, is this also not the same as "he died fighting"?)

Comment: I don't find it idiomatic to speak of people *dying frozen, dying starved, dying stabbed, dying shot,* etc. Anything's *possible* in English, but usually, if you're talking about people in a famine-stricken area, you'd say they were *dying from starvation*, not *dying starved*. In your case, perhaps *dying of frostbite*, but there may not be an ideal turn of phrase in this *exact* (quirky) context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **need** *one* in that sentence: including it or not is perfectly valid, but the resultant sentences mean different things.

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never heard of anyone falling inside.

Inside what? The refrigerator. **That** refrigerator. If you don't specify the noun to which *inside* refers, it's understood to be the nearest one which makes sense. Here, it's *the refrigerator:* the refrigerator the protagonist has opened.

> I tugged open the refrigerator. A relatively safe place; I’d never heard of anyone falling inside one.

Inside what? A refrigerator. **Any** refrigerator. Here, we know it's a refrigerator because that's what *one* must refer to (ask "One what?"). But *one* is not **the** refrigerator: it's any refrigerator, the general case.